# i am getting empty response when i am sending data($_GET method) to server(codeigniter) using angular js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter

I am trying to submit form data using angular js to server (codeigniter)
my for data is:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">First name: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" ng-model="fname">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Last name: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" ng-model="lname">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="email">
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" ng-model="csrfData" ng-init="csrfData='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();  ?>'" />
<input type="hidden"  ng-model="baseData" ng-init="baseData='<?=base_url();?>'" />
    <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a  class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-click="basicInfoAdd()">
        <span>Next Section </span>
        </a>
        <!--ui-sref="reg.professional"-->       
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my angular js controller code is

```
controller("basicInfo",function($scope,$http){
   $scope.new_user = true;
   $scope.basicInfoAdd = function(){
       //alert($scope.baseData);
       $http.get($scope.baseData+"angReg/basicReg/2",{'csrf_test_name':$scope.csrfData,'fname':$scope.fname,'lname':$scope.lname,'email':$scope.email})
       .then(function(response){
                      alert(response.data);
                      })           
       }
```

and my server side code is

```
   public function basicReg()
     { 
      $data  = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
      echo  $clmdata  = $data->fname;

    }
```

please tell me what is wrong in my code...?

Comment: sir, first you try to print baseData in console/alert please. i think the url not working.

Comment: sir i have modified my angular controllar code:


controller("basicInfo",function($scope,$http){
   $scope.new_user = true;
   $scope.basicInfoAdd = function(){
       //alert($scope.baseData);
       $http.get($scope.baseData+"angReg/basicReg",{'csrf_test_name':$scope.csrfData,'fname':$scope.fname,'lname':$scope.lname,'email':$scope.email})
       .then(function(response){
                      alert(response.data);
                      })           
       }

Comment: when i am trying to print form data on codeigniter controller then it give us an empty result. but when i echo something like echo "test" then it comes in response perfectly

Comment: i dont know what is wrong in my code

Comment: request is hitting the codeigniter controller but it dose not show any request  data. but when i echo something on server side code the it display that data.  I dont know what is the problem in my request data. or there is problem in server side code. please someone help me

Comment: got the exact issue. but not the solution...when i use put() instead of get() then its working fine. even i am not sending any file